# Can we convert ISingleResult<T> to IList<T>

Tags: linq-to-sql, collections

I started using LINQ to SQL recently. On my DMBL designer, I open the server explorer and drag a stored proc onto the designer.

I open the properties for the Method in the designer and see that its return type is AutoGenerated. I look at the designer.cs class and it says
the return type is `ISingleResult<GetEmloyeeeRecordDataResult>`.

Can this be cast to `IList<GetEmployeeRecordDataResult>`?

I tried doing this and there are no compile time errors. I am trying to understand what a `ISingleResult<T>` is and how it can be cast to `IList<T>`.

Comment: `ISingleResult` is `IEnumerable`, and this should be enough, why do you need `IList`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)